# DOM event not working with server side rendering in React js and node js application

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a application which using React js and node js as backend. 
Here is my code :

I am using above code, any events like onclick and form submit is not working. Please let me know any reference or help to run my application.

```
    Class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: 'Initial data...'
        }

        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    }
    updateState() {
       console.log('event is working');
    }
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick={this.updateState}>CLICK</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. This code should work perfectly error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I am not getting console log in updateState. Can you please help